# Simple Input Based Onblur JS Event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get an "OnBlur Event" done. It's an input based OnBLur Event. I am trying to display a "message" if the input is not correct and another one if it's correct.

[image: Img]

But due to some reason, it doesn't work. I Have Also Attached the Screenshot of the Error it's showing.

**I've tried** to change the Variable name and everything to the best of my beginner's knowledge.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OnBLur</title>
    //OnBlur Coding
    <script>
        function checkField() {
           var field = document.getElementbyId("field1").value;

           if (field.length < 5)
               document.getElementbyId("message1").innerHTML = "Too Short";
           else
               document.getElementbyId("message1").innerHTML = "Oky";
        }
    </script>

    <input id="field1" type="text" onblur="checkField();"/>
    <span id="message1"></span>
</head>
<body>
...
```

This is what it's supposed to do;

1. If the Input is <5 THEN it should display, "Too Short"
2. If the Input is >5 THEN, "Okay"

Comment: Voted to close - simple typographical error - should be `getElementById()`

Comment: Thank You. I am making a lot of mistakes in Typo`s. I need to gear up. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nice that you have started coding! You have done everything right. It is just the matter of a camelCase miss.
it should be `getElementById` with a capital 'B' on by.

Happy coading!

Comment: Thank You. Typo`s are becoming my Achelis Heel. I need to gear up. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: There are great tools to assist you with checking this. I don't know what you are using for writing your code but editors like VsCode, Atom, Sublime and Webstorm would have shown you this error in the text editor directly probably :)

Comment: Thank You. That info would help a lot:):):):)

Comment: The thing is these editors will weaken "my beginner's steps" by helping me. Once I grow into Coding, I will definitely go for them. :):):)